# jquery mobile datatables fillter

Tags: jquery-mobile

here i am useing smarty in head section me add all jquery mobile library...but i can not add fillter functionality.. i do not know what is wrong in my code.. i want to add fillter option in my datatables..

```
{extends file="./main.tpl"}
{block name=head}
  <meta name=viewport content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
{/block}
{block name=body}
<table cellspacing="0" class="ui-responsive table-stroke" data-role="table" id="sample" data-mode="columntoggle" data-top-container="true" data-bottom-container="true" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" align="center" border="1">
    <h2 align="center"><b>Loan List</b></h2>
    <tr>
        <th align="center">Party</th>
        <th align="center">Phone Number</th>
        <th align="center">Date</th>
        <th align="center">Amount</th>
        <th align="center">Interst</th>
        <th align="center">Given Amount</th>
    </tr>
    {section name="sec" loop=$loanListArray}
    <tr>
    <td align="left">{$loanListArray[sec].partyName}</td>
      <td align="left">{$loanListArray[sec].phoneNumber}</td>
      <td align="left">{$loanListArray[sec].loanDate|date_format:"%e-%m-%Y"}</td>
      <td align="right">{$loanListArray[sec].amount}</td>
      <td align="right">{$loanListArray[sec].interst}</td>
      <td align="right">{$loanListArray[sec].givenAmount}</td>
    </tr>
    {/section}
    <tr>
        <th align="right" colspan="3">Total :</th>
        <th>{$totalAmm}</th>
        <th>{$totalInt}</th>
        <th>{$totalgiven}</th>`enter code here`
    </tr>
    </table>

{/block}
```

Answer (score 1):

A table definition needs a `<thead>` and a `<tbody>` section. Per the JQM documentation:
"Be sure to include thead and tbody elements in your table". Hope that helps.